# Match a string when the pattern exists except when starting with it

Tags: python, regex

I want to strip out the spaces, parentheses, and characters which come *after* another words. For instance,

- hello (hi) -> hello
- hello(hi) -> hello
- hello (hi) bonjour -> hello
- (hi) hello bonjour -> (hi) hello bonjour
- (hi)_hello -> (hi)_hello

I've successfully done striping out the spaces and parentheses, but I can't stop it when it is at the beginning of the words.

```
re.sub("\s*\(.+", "", "hello(hi)")      # 'hello'
re.sub("\s*\(.+", "", "(hi)_hello")     # '', NOT desirable
re.sub("\w+\s*\(.+", "", "hello(hi)")   # '', NOT desirable
re.sub("\w+\s*\(.+", "", "(hi)_hello")  # '(hi)_hello'
```

I've also look up some documents about negative lookahead, but cannot get it so far.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: What about `hello (hi) hello`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ it should be turned into `hello`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `hello  hello` based on your example?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I want all characters after `(` to be eliminated. If there are spaces right before `(`, eliminate them as well. However, once the string starts with `(`, do nothing.

Comment: @ytu Is it critical to do this in a single regex? It would be much simpler to handle the two scenarios (string does/does not start with a bracket) with an if-else statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex with a negative lookbehind.

```
cases = [
    'hello (hi)', 
    'hello(hi)', 
    'hello (hi) bonjour', 
    '(hi) hello bonjour', 
    '(hi)_hello'
]
```

```
>>> [re.sub(r'(?<!^)\s*\(.*', '', i) for i in cases]
['hello', 'hello', 'hello', '(hi) hello bonjour', '(hi)_hello']
```

**Details**

```
(?<!   # negative lookbehind
^      # (do not) match the start of line
)     
\s*    # 0 or more spaces
\(     # literal parenthesis
.*     # match 0 or more characters (greedy)
```

Comment: Both answers of yours and @TamasRev's are great and helpful. Thank both of you. Unfortunately I can only accept one answer. I am going for the one whose replied earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You need a negative lookbehind: `(?<!^)`. The `(?<!...)` is the negative lookbehind. It means that don't match if you see `...` before the rest of the match.

In this case, you don't want to match in the beginning of the case, so your `...` will be `^`. I.e.:

```
re.sub("(?<!^)\s*\(.+", "", "(hi)_hello") # (hi_hello)
```

It still replaces the text if there are only spaces between the start of the line and the first parentheses:

```
re.sub("(?<!^)\s*\(.+", "", "  (hi)_hello") # ' '
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have to use regex, but because you use Python it could also be done like this:

```
lines = ["(hi) hello", "hello (hi)", "hello (hi) hello"]

for line in lines:
    result = line.split("(hi)")
    if(result[0] == ""):
        print(line)
    else:
        print(result[0])
```

Comment: This doesn't get rid of leading spaces before `(`.